# vector space dimensions question

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $4$, and $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation. Let $U=\ker(T)$ and suppose $T(x)\neq0$ for some $x\in V$. What are the possible values of dimension of $U$?

My attempt: so I can prove that $U$ is a subspace of $V$, so I know $\dim(U)$ must be less than or equal to $4$, but since clearly it isn't true that $U=V$ then it must be less than 4. What else am I missing? Thanks

Comment: any help with edit? I wasn't able to find (not equal to) symbol. thanks

Comment: Just type “\neq” for not equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right, if $T(x)\neq 0$ for some $x$ then $dim(U) <4$.

As an example, if it was also given that “for some $x\neq0$ we had $T(x)=0$“ then we could also conclude that $dim(U) >0$.

Comment: I doubt that interpreting "for some $x\in V$" as "for some but not all $x\in V\setminus\{0\}$" can be justified.

Comment: Yes I agree it was just an added consideration to give an example for the kindbof information needed to give a lower bound for dim(U).

Comment: I see since if for all x$\neq$0 then U would be an empty set, thanks!

Comment: I’ve modified a little bit the example in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The fact that $T(x)\ne0$ for some $x\in V$ implies that the rank of $T$ is $\ge1$. By the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\dim U=\dim V-\operatorname{rank}T=4-\operatorname{rank}T<4
$$
It's not difficult to show that any value between $0$ and $3$ can be taken.

Comment: thanks ,yes. And is it enough to say if U subspace of V then dimU less than or equal to dimV, without proving rank-nullity theorem , or does that require a proof, assuming we don't know rank-nullity theorem yet.

Comment: @Rivaldo Yes, your argument is good as well. The rank-nullity theorem helps in finding the examples where $\dim U$ is $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$.